# New append method on DOM Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

On firefox up to 48, Safari up to 9, IE and Chrome:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
alert(p.append); // undefined
```

But starting from firefox 49 and Safari 10  onwards:

```
alert(p.append); // function append () { native code }
```

What is this new native method append ?

It seems that the MDN, the place where I'm usually browsing for documentation, isn't yet updated, and I don't find much information about what does this new method and/or what changes has been made recently to those browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.createElement returns an Element object.
.append is an experimental method, find info here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Answer (score 2):

It's on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append), you need to look better :-)

> The **ParentNode.append** method inserts a set of Node objects or DOMString objects after the last child of the ParentNode. DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.

Comment: When I link to MDN I remove the `/en-US` part so: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append ... that way a french speaker (for example) is not forced to the english site.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way as the .appendChild() method.

Except in this case, it can also take in DOM objects along with node objects.

var text = document.createElement('div');

var container = document.createElement('div');

container.append(text); // The text div is now inserted into the container's DOM